# How to get user contact info

Tags: users

In the user profile in Dashboard I have a section 'Contact info' containing email, URL, aim, yahoo, jabber. I would like to build a widget and output that user info within the widget. What function should I use to get just the contact info of a user?

Comment: FYI: There's [the Codex function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/) and [QueryPosts.com](http://queryposts.com/)...

Comment: I know that, my question is more specific.

Comment: _"(...) What function should I use to get just the contact info of a user?"_ ... what is more specific here? I read your comment ↓ below. Why don't you add that info in your question from the beginning? With 109 questions I'm pretty sure you know how to ask a _complete_ question.

Comment: @drtanz what research did you perform before asking this question? what have you tried already?

Comment: I've checked get_user_meta() and get_userdata(). I also found _wp_get_user_contactmethods().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're after the [get_userdata()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) function.

As a basic example, you could retrieve a users email like this:

```
<?php
  if ( $user_id ) {
     $user = get_userdata($user_id);

     echo 'Users Email is: ' . $user->user_email;
  }
?>
```

Comment: So it isn't possible to get the fields of the contact info section automatically, without specifying them? My idea is to have email and url which are usually visible via get_userdata(), and also the social accounts like jabbar which are retrievable via get_user_meta(). The idea is to enable the user to add more accounts like 'skype' and have the widget be able to retrieve also these accounts without modification.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow the user to arbitrarily add accounts without knowing what those accounts are up front **you leave yourself open to problems**.

Say you have a `meta_key` for the user called `user_custom_social` and you provide a form that allows the user to add accounts such as,

```
Network Name                    URL
-------------------             ----------
facecrooks             --->     http://www.facecrooks.crooks/bob
mysocialwasteoftime    --->     http://www.mysocialwasteoftime.com/bob
```

Assume this user can't spell and as above spells Facebook as Facecrooks. When you iterate over these custom results the output will be erroneous.

If you also choose to display this information elsewhere, then the same erroneous information will be displayed.

To retrieve the values, you would do,

```
$meta = get_user_meta($user_id, $meta_key);
foreach ($meta as $key => $value){
echo $key . '=>' . $value;
}
```

Your best approach would be to define the social networks first so they can choose from a list.

Even if you decide to create a new meta_key per entry you are still going to be faced with the same problems of user input errors.

I would define my own list of social networks in a drop down with a input text field for their URL and then use,

The values you would get from the `$_POST` object except the `$user_id`,

```
$meta_key   = $_POST['network']; //will match the value selected from the drop down
$meta_value = $_POST['url']      //user entered input
```

Then,

```
add_user_meta($user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value);
```

To display its the same deal,

```
$meta = get_user_meta($user_id, $meta_key);
foreach ($meta as $key => $value){
echo $key . '=>' . $value;
}
```

Comment: What's the deal with down voting an answer without providing feedback as to why? This answer addresses the question & [the comment located here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67057/how-to-get-user-contact-info/67086#comment87937_67058). Down votes on answers that are plausible solutions are meaningless. It ain't about no rep, **its all about the solution**, ya get me?